# Is there any way to mock JNI methods in my android project to do Junit testing?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, java-native-interface

Hi I need to write Junit tests for an Android project but it has JNI methods as it uses webkit.Is there any way I can test those android methods(I dont want to test JNI methods).

Its like:

```
public void androidMethod(){

//some android code

  nativeInit();    //how do I mock such methods?

//some code again
}
```

I have tried powermock,easymock,roboelectric but wasnt successful.Please help me.

Comment: Do the methods have to be native? Just create a Java object that does the same thing as the native methods.

Comment: Hey ,thanks for helping.But I cannot change anything in the source code! :/  any other way?

Comment: What was the problem with powermock ? You should show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I yesterday found I could solve this with Mockito (I didn't try powermock or easymock). Assuming your class is class C, my solution is:

```
C c=spy(new C); 
doNothing().when(c).nativeInit();
c.androidMethod()
verify(c).nativeInit();
```

This does, of course, require that nativeInit is visible to the test.

Answer (score 0):

### Similar Problem

I had the same problem event though I was already using mockito in JUnit tests under `src/test`. Once I added tests under `src/androidTest` I started having issues, including this crash:

> Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
>   - final class

And after making the class `open`, manually, I still got crashes in the JNI layer as it tried to load the `*.so` library (which wouldn't happen if mocks were working properly).

### Working Solution

Instead, what I had to do was ***open the class*** for testing purposes using [Kotlin's all-open plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html). The process is also explained well in [this recent medium post](https://proandroiddev.com/mocking-androidtest-in-kotlin-51f0a603d500) but it boils down to the following four simple changes that are also modeled in [one of the architecture components sample apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample):

**1.** Make these additions to build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${versions.kotlin}"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"

    allOpen {
        // marker for classes that we want to be able to extend in debug builds
        annotation 'com.your.package.name.OpenClass'
    }
```

**2.** Add the [corresponding annotations](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/debug/java/com/android/example/github/testing/OpenForTesting.kt) in the debug flavor. For example: `app/src/debug/java/com/your/package/name/OpenForTesting.kt`

```
package com.your.package.name

@Target(AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS)
annotation class OpenClass

@OpenClass
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class OpenForTesting
```

**3.** Add the [corresponding annotation](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/release/java/com/android/example/github/testing/OpenForTesting.kt) in the release flavor. For example: `app/src/release/java/com/your/package/name/OpenForTesting.kt`

```
package com.your.package.name

@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class OpenForTesting
```

**4.** Add the `@OpenForTesting` annotation to the class that needs to be mocked

```
package com.your.package.name

@OpenForTesting
class JniClassOfVictory {
    ...
    external fun nativeInit()
    ...
    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("victoryeveryday")
        }
    }
}
```

The result is a flexible way to mark classes as open without actually making them open in release builds. Of course, this is because the `@OpenForTesting` annotation that we created in ***release is not marked*** with `@OpenClass` but the same annotation in ***debug is marked*** with `@OpenClass`. In `build.gradle` we designated that annotation as the signal to the `kotlin-allopen` plugin. So any class annotated with `@OpenForTesting` will be made open at compile-time but only on Debug builds.